# PassportJS not deserializing user on Heroku server

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, passport.js, firebase-hosting

I'm working on a project which is using PassportJS Google OAuth 2.0. When I test on my local machine (with a React client on localhost:3000 and a Express server on localhost:4000), the flow works fine. I am able to send requests to the server and deserialize the user on each request. However, when I host the client on Google Firebase Hosting and the server on Heroku, the user no longer get deserialized on each request.

Here are some specifics of the things I've done / tried / worked locally along with extra information:

The client and server and hosted on different domains.

I am using axios to send the request to the server. In the request, I make sure to set the "withCredentials" property in the options to true to make sure the cookies connected to that domain are sent on each request.

On the server I have CORS enabled for the domain the client is hosted on (as it is currently being hosted on a different domain) and I have "credentials" set to true to allow the credentials to be sent and received.

Please let me know if I've forgotten to include something in the post or if any extra information would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you fix this, but I got the exact same problem, in my case I added sameSite: "none" in my express session setting, it worked.

```
cookie: {
  sameSite: "none", //add this line
  ...
},
```